# How to fetch all the first records of different date in a list using linq

Tags: sql-server, list, date

I have this table named sample with these values in MS Sql Server.

```
ID    Date                 Description
1    2012/01/02 5:12:43    Desc1
2    2012/01/02 5:12:48    Desc2
3    2012/01/03 5:12:41    Desc3
4    2012/01/03 5:12:43    Desc4
```

I want to write LINQ query that will fetch the first record for each day. Desired output:

```
 2012/01/02 5:12:43 
 2012/01/03 5:12:41
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What are the requirements ? Why these results and not others ?

Comment: Changed the text to be more clear what is expected

Comment: This is my Project requirement. I have to fetch first entry for each date

Comment: Thanks Guys for your suggestions. Olly has already answered fr my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you mean that, for each distinct date, you want to return the first (sequentially or chronologically?) date and time. If so, try

```
from r in rows
group r by r.Date into g
select g.First()
```

This will give you *one* `DateTime` for each distinct date. To be explicit that you want the *earliest* `DateTime` for each date, use:

```
from r in rows
group r by r.Date into g
select (from t in g
        order by t
        select t).First()
```